# What's the purpose of ''this'' thing?

Tags: identification

Recently a colleague of mine asked the purpose of the following part:

[image]

[image]

I wasn't sure but I suspect it's an [Snubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber) of some kind.

He said he wasn't able to measure ''any current'' flowing through*, which would make sense for a circuit containing a capacitor.

*I don't know the exact setup he used.

Update: full photo of the instruction manual *(as requested)*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it the rectangle shown connected to L2 of upper double switch (col 2 of instructions) and perhaps is the "accessory" for preventing flashing (end of instructions)?

Comment: Are there any markings on the front side?

Comment: Can you add pictures of the rest of the instructions?

Comment: @GrahamNye I see what I can do.

Comment: @GrahamNye I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @winny He said there were not any markings.

Comment: Thanks for the remaining instructions. Unfortunately they don't clearly explain what to do with the unknown part but it did prompt me to spot a scrap of information on the original post. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be a capacitor, intended to be connected in parallel with one of the switched lights and used to allow the operating current of the zigbee module to return to neutral.

Note there is no neutral connection on the module and indeed the instructions warn against connecting neutral to the module. The module however needs a neutral connection to power its electronics (separate to the current required to power the attached lamps). With incandescent lamps this operating current can return to neutral through the lamp and is too small to make the lamp light up. With low energy lamps (CFL, LED) this small current can charge up a capacitor in the lamp causing it to flash occasionally. Connecting a capacitor across the lamp provides a route for the AC current to return to neutral without making the lamp flash. This roundabout method allows smart modules to be used in switch locations without a neutral connection, common in the pre-smart switch era.

The first page of the instructions show an unlabelled box connected in parallel with a lamp in one diagram, though not the other. The instructions should advise connecting the capacitor across one of the lamps.

At the bottom-right of the first page of instructions it states:

`5. If the light flashes after turning off, please connect the accessories.`

This is the only, very vague, reference I can see to connecting the unknown part. However preventing the lights from flashing is the point of connecting a capacitor across a lamp.

Providing such a capacitor is a trend in recent smart switch modules without an explicit neutral connection. The cheaper ones may not have good instructions though. Here's an [example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/MOES-Neutral-Compatible-Control-Available/dp/B08KSTTRVQ/) of a (different) smart switch that uses such a capacitor.

It is possible to buy capacitors [packaged for this use](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E9F084E) (shows US wiring practice).

An RC snubber isn't required for a CFL or LED lamp. It could be useful for a lamp with an inductive ballast such as a traditional fluorescent lamp, though the power factor correction capacitor already included in such lamps will act as a snubber.